# Citadel: Inspirational Stories is not finishing

Tags: mass-effect-3

I agreed to do the Citadel: Inspirational Stories mission for a salarian who wants to make a documentary. However, I can't find any more locations that trigger for it. I've run around the entire docking area now, to no avail.

To note, I *was* able to do the following:

- One area in the Memorial Wall that didn't count
- A grieving couple in the Memorial wall that did count
- A Turian standing around that didn't

After that, nothing else has popped up throughout the entire docks. Is the quest bugged? Did I miss my chance to finish it by clicking on incorrect things? It's not greyed out, so I'm *assuming* I'm still able to finish it somehow, but I can't find any more waypoints.

What can I do?

Updating with an image to show my view of the poker table. There's no other reticule other than speaking to James.

[image: citadel]

Comment: I finished that a bit ago. Did you get a picture of someone on a stretcher in one of the cargo stack niches?

Comment: No, I haven't had any other clickables pop up other than the ones I listed.

Comment: Double check the refugee areas, amidst the cargo containers, there really should be a picture opprotunity in there.

Comment: Clicking incorrect things doesn't count against you - I practically clicked on everything that showed up, and was still able to finish the quest. If I recall correctly, there should only be 3 or 4 shots.

Comment: I think there's 4 shots counting the two he says don't count. I don't know if those are actually required or not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After fruitlessly doublechecking some more, reloading my save and losing some playtime, having the same thing happen, and then doing some more googling, it seems that this is apparently a **known bug**.

There are [several](http://social.bioware.com/forum/Mass-Effect-3/Mass-Effect-3-PC-Technical-Support/Problem-on-Citadel-Inspiration-stories-9672401-1.html) [other](http://social.bioware.com/forums/forum/1/topic/323/index/9668714/2#9746284) [people](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/345/index/9693004) reporting this problem on the Bioware Social Network as well.

The solution that worked for me (after loading another save) is to **go immediately to the areas that count as valid photo opportunities** for the quest, **skipping over** the ones that do not count.

The following **4** locations are valid photo opportunities for this sidequest, though you only need **3** of them to count. You can click through images for larger versions:

### The mourning woman being comforted by the salarian in the Memorial Wall:

[image: first]
[image: first-map view]

### The woman speaking with the man sitting on the crate between Bay E24 and Bay E26:

[image: second]
[image: second-map view]

### The doctors treating patients on makeshift stretchers made out of crates in Cargo Hold: B:

[image: third]
[image: third-map view]

### James playing poker with other refugees in the far end of the hall in what is technically Bay E28:

[image: fourth]
[image: fourth-map view]

For reference, the following are the locations which **do not count**. **Avoid** clicking these if you want to avoid the bug!

### The stack of crates in the left area of the Memorial Wall

[image: wrong1]

### The Turian standing on guard between Bay E24 and Bay E26

[image: wrong2]

### The monitors behind the counter that's closest to the poker table

[image: wrong3]

From what I can tell, if you save *during* this quest, it will remain bugged and you will not be able to complete it. Reloading a save after it has already started and you have already encountered the bug will not fix it. You need to load one *prior* to the mission bugging out.

Comment: *grr* another bugged quest that hits me in this game...

Comment: Nice answer! :D

Comment: Hmm, I've done this twice already, and haven't had it bug out on me (360).  Both times, I clicked on the turian guard.

Answer (score 0):

I believe (from doing the quest completely myself) that you are missing the picture by the table where james vega is sitting and playing a card game with a few others. you have to practically jump on the table to get it.

Comment: There's no reticule at the table for me. :/

Comment: hmm then i am stumped it is possible you may have gotten a bugged mission, idk where your at but maybe loading a previous save may fix it. although when i found it i did approach it from the other side of the table doubt it will make a difference, haha

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of hearing James, but not seeing him.  He just was not there.  To fix it, I saved game and then reloaded it.  Then he was there, but there's no proper conversation to have with him, anyway!

(I'm playing on PC)