# How do I trigger the picture-taking mission?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've heard there is a mission on the Citadel where you walk around and use your Omni-tool to snap some photos for the quest-giver. I'm always a fan of this kind of thing in games, and I'd like try out this Mass Effect variation.

**Where do I need to go and who do I need to talk to get the picture-taking quest on the Citadel?**

(I *shutter* to think how sad I'd be without *exposure* to this mission, even if it's over in a *flash*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is the one I'm thinking of, it is called [**Inspirational Stories**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel:_Inspirational_Stories)

You can obtain this mission any time after the Assault on the Citadel.  Located in the Supply bay holding all of the refugees of the war

All it is, is a quest given by a Salarian asking you to capture how the war is affecting the refugees where you just go around the area and interact with a few areas with civilians around and then return to him (similar to the "scan the keepers" mission in ME1)

It is nothing special and flashy, sadly.

From ME wiki entry, linked above:

> After Solik presents his requests, there are three photo opportunity locations you need to take in the docks.
>
> -At the Memorial Hall where a salarian is consoling a grieving woman.
>
> -The area between Bay E24 and Bay E26, where a woman is having a conversation with a batarian.
>
> -The area between Bay E26 and Bay E28, where James is playing poker with three other players.
>
> There are also two other photo opportunity areas located at the crates in the Memorial Hall and a turian security officer at Bay E26. However, the footages are unsuitable for Solik's film and he will ask you to look for other photo opportunities.
>
> Note: There appears to be a glitch or a limit to the available photo opportunities where the option do not appear at the players playing poker. To resolve the issue, reload to a save game before the mission and do not take any unsuitable footage as mentioned above but go directly to the three locations instead.
>
> After taking the photos, return to Solik and give him the footage. You will receive 5 reputation, 210 experience and 5000 credits.

Comment: I think the mission only came up after the station attack, either that or I just didn't notice the guy until then

Comment: I honestly do not remember either, either way, it is technically *after* Palaven :)

Comment: It does only appear after the station attack. Also [related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55769/citadel-inspirational-stories-is-not-finishing).

Comment: Looking around, it appears you're right in that it is obtainable *after* the attack

Comment: Definitely check out @FAE's link, as you have the potential to end up in a bugged state.